# OnePlus Chrome, different user agent on AJAX

Tags: android, ajax, google-chrome, mobile

I discovered a very annoying issue with Chrome browser on (some) OnePlus mobile devices. I tested it on 3T, and 5T models. With normal GET request, the browser sends the following user agent to the server:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; ONEPLUS A5010 Build/OPR1.170623.032) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

But with AJAX XMLHttpRequest the user agent is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; Build/OPR1.170623.032) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Missing the "ONEPLUS A5010" string. What's meaning this difference? I've spent hours to debug, why my project see two different browsers, because i'm using only one.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47904396/1989973